# How do I make an image inside a div tag responsive when window is resized?

Tags: css

I currently have this arrow image inside a div and I want it to be responsive with my page when I resize it. It is a little hard for me to explain but this I what I want to achieve 
[This is when it is  in full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5CDd.png) . [This is when it is minimized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Hp0G.png)
I have already tried using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`to make it responsive but it does not work.

```css
#secondArrow {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 530px;
  right: 340px;
  margin: auto 5px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="secondArrow">
  <a href="javascript:showImage()"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" alt="" width="100" height="100"></a>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add some code so we can help you.

Comment: I have added my html code :)

Comment: You can set the width="100%" height="auto" in your html.

Comment: You should use `media-query` for responsiveness so you can apply different css properties at different viewports.

Answer (score 0):

add class="img-responsive" to your img tag if you are using bootstrap or write this css for the img max-width: 100%, height: auto, and display:block`

```css
.img-responsive{
max-width: 100%; 
height: auto;
display:block
}
```

```html
<img class="img-responsive" src="">
```

`

Comment: can you inspect and check if the css is getting applied?

Comment: Yes it is applied

Comment: It gets applied, but you use max-width and load a 100x100px image inside it... Just apply width: 100% to the image AND parent container. He wants the image forced to be full width.

Answer (score 0):

This will help -:

```
//css
.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
//html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" alt="" class="responsive" width="100" height="100">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below code..

**css**

```
#secondArrow img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```